# Selecting committees using the single transferable vote

Tags: voting-systems

Let's say we are electing a single district of twenty representatives using the single transferable vote. This is an unusually large district, but that's what it is.

We would also like to select five committees, each of four representatives, such that every representative in the district is on one committee. We would like these committees to be as proportional as possible.

Is there a established way to do this using the ballots cast for the original election? If not, is there an obvious way to do it?

Comment: Are you doing this as a two stage election? One to choose the representatives and then one to decide which committes they are on? And what do you mean by "proportional"? And who is voting for the committes, the representitives or the whole electorate?  (By the way, this sounds a lot like a theoretical electoral systems question rather than one of politics).

Comment: This is a very specific case. Are the specifics necessary? Could you ask the question in a more generalizable way?

Comment: @DJClayworth Single stage - electors cast one vote each in the whole thing. I admit i don't exactly know what i mean by "proportional". The electorate is voting for the committees (using the same vote as they cast for the district). This is definitely a technical electoral system question; is that off-topic here?

Comment: @divibisan I could phrase it more generically. Would that be useful? Personally, i find specific examples like this easier to grasp.

Comment: Seriously? Who was obnoxious enough to downvote this question and why? If this type of practical question is not only on topic but also excellent, we should be shutting down Politics SE. Nearly everything else that gets asked here belongs in a forum.

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_vote relevant?

Comment: I don't understand how any permutation of membership in "20 representatives into five committees of four representantives, every representative in one committee" could be more or less 'proportional' than any other.  If you could clarify please.

Comment: @Roger If the district has ten Big-Endians and ten Little-Endians, and two of the committees have four Big-Endians, two have four Little-Endians, and one has two of each, then that's not proportional, because there are four committees whose makeup does not reflect the division of opinion in the electorate. You would ideally have all five committees have two from each party.

Comment: @endolith That is a different approach to the overall problem, but yes, that might work. I need to have a think about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ballots cast for the original election, with the caveat that some votes might end up not counting if you had a lot more candidates than elected representatives. (Consider doing a new election for this purpose if that was the case.)

In non-profits it's common (source: worked with an electronic voting company in the past) to elect several officials in a single pass using STV. The top candidate becomes President, the next becomes General Secretary, the next Treasurer, etc. until all roles are filled. You can optionally swap positions according to the top candidates' preferences, a bit like what happens in competitive exams (e.g. if #2 wants to be Treasurer, then let them do so and continue assigning roles based on the ranked order).

You could arguably adapt this for multiple committees. Have voters rank order candidates, tally the results, and assign committee positions based  on candidate preferences and the results until all positions are filled.

It's reasonable to add a constraint in there to ensure that there is a degree of proportionality in each committee. Specifically, disallow that any committee have more seats held by candidates with a certain color than the proportion of votes that they got overall (round up). For instance, if one party has 6 seats, there are 20 seats in total, and 5 committees, then there are 4 seats per committee, and that party can have more than 4 * 6 / 20 rounded up = 2 seats per committee at most. (You could require a minimum of one seat per committee in this case by rounding down.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the representatives are members of parties, for some reason, and that the proportionality of the committees should reflect the relative sizes of the parties, then the obvious way of assigning representatives is:

Start with the party with the most representatives.  Pull out a representative and put it into a committee.  Then pull out the next representative and put it into the next committee.  Repeat until you run out of representatives.

Repeat with the next most populous party.  Continue until all representatives are assigned.

That might not be clear, so an example:

20 Representatives:  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T

Five Committees of four members:  ()  []  {}  <>  «»

Parties:

- Party $ has 10 members:  A B C D E F G H I J
- Party & has 5 members: K L M N O
- Party * has 3 members: P Q R
- Party ~ has 2 members: S T

Round 1 of assignment -- starting with Party $:

- (A)
- [B]
- {C}
- < D >
- «E»

Round 2 of assignment -- continuing with Party $:

- (A F)
- [B G]
- {C H}
- < D I >
- «E J»

Round 3 of assignment -- finished with Party $; starting with Party &:

- (A F K)
- [B G L]
- {C H M}
- < D I N >
- «E J O»

Round 4 of assignment -- finished with Party; starting with Party *:

- (A F K P)
- [B G L Q]
- {C H M R}
- < D I N >
- «E J O»

Round 5 of assignment -- finished with Party *; starting with Party ~:

- (A F K P)
- [B G L Q]
- {C H M R}
- < D I N S >
- «E J O T»

And then we're done.